# Connection from external computer to computer in local network

Tags: c++, qt

Currently in my chat p2p app, I need to open the port for other computers can connect to, but static ip is not allowed by the admin to open the port. Then I found a network programming exercise that seemed like a solution to this problem. The requirements are as follows:
"Write a program to test the UPnP protocol to
ADSL modem controller opens NAT gateway automatically.
In case you can not control the modem, find out and install a NAT Traversal technique to connect two clients in two NAT networks.
internet (use an intermediary server for primers
connect)."
Can anyone tell me what is an intermediate server for connection primitives?

Comment: It's a server to which both parties connect to, so they can 'discover' each other there.

Comment: Hi! How they can 'discover' each other? what the server do?

Answer (score 0):

You can simple setup DynDNS services. You will have one external domain name with any ip address.

But best way to setup [SoftEther VPN](http://www.softether.org/) solution. That can pass thought any NAT. You can keep your application server at the NAT subnetwork too. And that server will registered on common EtherVPN registry that allow connects from anywhere.

If you want smart solution embedded in your application. Please check similar solutions for VoIP communications. Like ICE, STUN, TURN. But that will not simple to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Check [https://www.noip.com/ :P](https://www.noip.com/). Maybe this can solve some of your problems ^^